# Sending Ctrl+K Ctrk+U does not work, Ctrl+K Ctrl+C does

Tags: ssms, send, autohotkey

I just play around a bit with AHK and I thought I could outsource some of my SSMS macros to AHK.

Now I have a problem with a rather simple macro:

```
;+++++ ALT + ScrollUp +++++
!WheelUp::
;##### SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO #####
IfWinActive, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
{
    Send, {Control Down}ku{Control Up}
}

;+++++ ALT + ScrollDown +++++
!WheelDown::
;##### SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO #####
IfWinActive, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
{
    Send, {Control Down}kc{Control Up}
}
```

So if I scroll down while pressing the Alt key, I want it to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to SSMS (Comment selection). This works fine, but if I want to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (Uncomment selection) it only uncomments it for a millisecond before it gets commented again.

Now the code is not really complex, what am I missing?

I've already tried to change the hotkey to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Scrolling or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Scrolling, same effect. I also tried to bind it to a normal key like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if you put a return after each Wheelcommand it will work. Now it will continue with the next command (undoing your initial command).

```
;+++++ ALT + ScrollUp +++++
!WheelUp::
;##### SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO #####
IfWinActive, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
{
    Send, {Control Down}ku{Control Up}
}
Return

;+++++ ALT + ScrollDown +++++
!WheelDown::
;##### SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO #####
IfWinActive, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
{
    Send, {Control Down}kc{Control Up}
}
Return
```

Let me know how this works!

Comment: B.t.w., you might have to pause this after one command is sent, since scolling up/down will initiate multiple send's...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I always thought, that things inside the hotkey definition will only fire, if the hotkey is pressed. But as I look at it, there isn't even an "inside" of the hotkey, so it's just the startpoint. Thanks for your help, it works now.